# How to ignore one or more web projects publishing on TFS 2013?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, publishing

There is a VS2013 solution with multiple web projects. And only two of them should be published on TFS 2013 server. Both projects have a valid build.pubxml own publish profiles. Other web projects don't have publish profiles because I don't want to publish them.

TFS build is broken with the following exception: 
*C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (4346): The value for PublishProfile is set to 'build.pubxml', expected to find the file at 'C:\Builds\1...\PublishProfiles\build.pubxml' but it could not be found.*

My question is how I can ignore projects publishing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> EDIT: Updated as my original answer didn't work and caused the build
>   to blow up. have now suggested to create a zip package, but to not
>   actually deploy the web application. Same Idea different implementation

Add dummy build.pubxml file to each of the unwanted projects and set them to not publish, but to generate a package, will work and not automatically publish the site.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>Package</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>True</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <DesktopBuildPackageLocation>Webapplication2.zip</DesktopBuildPackageLocation>
    <PackageAsSingleFile>true</PackageAsSingleFile>
    <DeployIisAppPath>webapplication2</DeployIisAppPath>
    <PublishDatabaseSettings>
      <Objects xmlns="" />
    </PublishDatabaseSettings>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This should allow the build to find a publishing profile, Create a zip file for the unwanted web apps but not actually deploy them.